# Can assembly version been automatically updated with each TFS 2010 Build?

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and TFS 2010. Is there a way that dll version be automatically incremented with each TFS build?

Thanks

Comment: I wrote a blog post about my total experience with versioning in Team Build 2010: http://afsharm.blogspot.com/2010/07/versioning-assemblies-with-team-build.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a blog post on how to version your assemblies in TFS Build 2010:
[How to Create a Custom Workflow Activity for TFS Build 2010 RTM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jimlamb/create-a-custom-wf-activity-to-sync-version-and-build-numbers)

Comment: I have spent a full day on reading your post and applying it on my project. I corrected all issues one by one. But finally it does not update `AssemblyVersion` in `AssemblyInfo.cs` without any error. In addition I didn't find anything in your sample code that indicates changes will be commit back on the source control. Also you blog post does not allow me to comment there.

Comment: There's no need to commit the changes back to source control since the version is based on the build number. Modifying files in source control during a build is generally something you'll want to avoid. Are your assemblies getting versioned, or not?

Comment: I now understand why no activity exists with source control. But assemblies are still not versioned. I traced the process by adding `WriteBuildWarning` just before calling `ReplaceInFile`, so I'm sure `ReplaceInFile` is executed. I just tried to use `UpdateVersionInfo` instead but still no assembly is versioned. I have put the activity in `Overal Build Process\ Run On Agent` just before `Initialize Variables` activity. May this be the root cause of `ReplaceInFile` and `UpdateVersionInfo` not to function?

Comment: Finally I got Activity Pack to work. Now it works greatly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try [TfsVersioning](https://web.archive.org/web/20180108183608/http://tfsversioning.codeplex.com:80/) build definition. It can be alse extended with [Nugetter](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128221307/http://nugetter.codeplex.com:80/) to create a NuGet package and upload it to a repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Version task from [msbuildtasks](https://web.archive.org/web/20200701145914/http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)

Here's [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160216063137/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jjameson/archive/2010/03/25/incrementing-the-assembly-version-for-each-build.aspx) by Jeremy Jameson with step-by-step instructions on how to use it.

Comment: That blog post is about TFS 2008 and build tasks. But I'm searching for a TFS 2010 solution. TFS 2010 uses WF 4.0 instead of build tasks.

Comment: @afsharm: just add MSBuild workflow activity to use task that you need.

Comment: would you please explain how to do it?